# Laravel do something based on one or more eloquent results

Tags: php, laravel, search, eloquent

So I have a search function, and based on the results I want to show different views, or redirect, etc. Right now I am doing the following:

```
public function search()
{
    $results = Event::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$this->search}%")->get();

    if ($results)
    {
        if ($results->count() > 1)
        {
            // return an index view with all search results
        }

        // There was only one result so we grab the result and redirect to the show view

        $result = Event::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$this->search}%")->first();
        
        return redirect()->route(__('events.show'), [$result->slug]);
    }

    // No results
}
```

And yes although this does work, I would like to know if there is a way to get the same result without having to do multiple queries like I am doing now. Is it possible to achieve this with only one query? I do not wish to loop through the collection that I get from the initial `->get()` results though.

I am aware I could do a `firstOr` or a `firstOrFail` for example, but I do not wish to redirect upon the `first` result, I still want to check if there is more than one result, and if so, to display all those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` returns a collection. You could just do `first()` or `get(0)` on the Collection itself to return the first result.

```php
$results = Event::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$this->search}%")->get();

if ($results->isNotEmpty()) {
    return $results->count() === 1
        ? view('show', ['event' => $results->first()])
        : view('index', ['results' => $results]);
}

return view('no-results');
```

Comment: Nice, amazing, learned something cool again, thanks a lot for this!